# fatal: Authentication failed since update to 2017 Update 3.1

Tags: tfs

We have authentication problems since we update our TFS server from 2017 update 1 to update 3.1. (everything works fine just before the update)

Most of the time, the authentication works, but sometimes, it doesn't. I cannot really explain what is happening.

EG : A user was able to connect from web interface, from Poweshell but wasn't able to use sourceTree anymore.

Also, the Endpoints created in the Services section have the same problem, We are unable to to a Git fetch. Same error message.

**fatal: Authentication failed for 'http:**//********:********@xxxx

Any tips on it?

Comment: Have you ever updated the password for your account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at my backup and I think we found the problem, each time we update TFS, the authentication method switch from NTS to Kerboros.

Don't understand why this setting change.

Need to use the following command to return to NTLM

TFSConfig Authentication /provider:NTLM /siteType:ApplicationTier

Answer (score 6):

Just try below items to narrow down the issue:

- Update the cached credentials for git:

  1. Go to `Control Panel -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials (Generic Credentials)`
  2. Then update the password for `git:http://ServerName:xxx/`
  3. If there is nothing that starts with `git:http...`, go and ADD the generic credentials:

  [image]
- Set up authentication with [credential managers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/set-up-credential-managers) or [SSH](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate).

  Download and run the latest Git for Windows installer, which includes the Git Credential Manager for Windows. Make sure to leave the Git Credntial Manager installation option enabled when prompted.

  [image]
- For SourceTree:

  Navigate to `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree` and remove the `passwd` file.

  Also try other ways mentioned by others in this thread: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Getting-quot-fatal-Authentication-failed-for-quot-error/qaq-p/624663

Comment: Thanks for sourcetree, I will look at it. It looks like it was another issue. But my general problem seems to be with SSH keys due to the authentification mode. 

The update of TFS switch from NTLM to Negociate and that's why this part broked.

Answer (score 0):

how to fixed tfs Authentication problem
-> go through the location 
Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager
-> remove some credentials related to tfs.

1. Delete all credentials that have TFS anywhere in the name/url in the Credential Manager 
   (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager)
2. Clear the TFS Cache on the client machine The folder path is: 
   C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache.